# How to launch app after every given intervals on OSX

Tags: macos, automator

Im looking to launch an app (eg calendar) after an interval eg (10 mins)

Using Automator or any similar way would be appreciated.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a LaunchAgent / LaunchDaemon. More technical informations about this service: 
http://launchd.info

There is an easy GUI application that let you create such agent: Lingon, available here: https://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/

You can define an interval to repeatedly launch an application.